# Android network permission not granted for application from unknown source

Tags: android

My app requires `android.permission.INTERNET`.  When I run it over USB debugging, it successfully makes a socket connection.

When I download it via the browser from an "unknown source" aka my website, it asks for Internet permissions and I give it.  When the app successfully launches, the socket connection cannot be made.

Is there something I am missing that would complete the socket connection when downloading my app from an unknown source?

I have verified the string `android.permission.INTERNET` is in the binary, compiled `AndroidManifest.xml` in the apk I am distributing.

Comment: I am using native sockets via NDK.

Comment: Strange story. Hard to believe. It should not make any difference.

Comment: Maybe also try adding this: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

Comment: I added that as a safety precaution.  No difference.

Comment: I am starting to wonder if this problem is outside of permissions.  What else changes when you install an app from a website vs. debug it over USB that would block sockets?

Comment: Android does not change it. I have an app that requires network connection and it works pretty well when installed from my website. Maybe you run the connection through ADB?

Comment: The app is debug signed.  Is this a problem?  From Android docs: "You can run and debug an app signed in debug mode on the emulator and on devices connected to your development manchine through USB, but you cannot distribute an app signed in debug mode."

Comment: ... nope.  Release signed android build did not solve the problem.

Comment: Swapping out the precompiled libcurl.a with another one (from a friend's build) caused it to work.  So, the problem is somewhere inside libcurl.a.